# Difference between find('option[selected]') and find('option').filter('[selected]')

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, html-select

### Scenario:

I got 2 jQuery expressions:

```
/* A */ $('select').find('option[selected]');
/* B */ $('select').find('option').filter('[selected]');
```

which mean (let's assume there's only one `select` in the document, for simplicity):

- **A**: Get the `select`, then find all `option` descendants that has an attribute named `selected`.
- **B**: Get the `select`, then find all `option` descendants, then filter by those who has an attribute named `selected`.

### Expected Behaviour:

**A** and **B** should give the same result.

### Actual Behaviour:

After the user changed the selection in the dropdown,

- **A** returns the *default* selected `option`.
- **B** returns the *new* selected `option`.

### Question:

So why are they different? Is my understanding about CSS selectors wrong?

### Live Demo:

Live demo is <strike>[here](http://jsfiddle.net/ugXtx/4/)</strike> [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ugXtx/9/).

### Source Code:

**HTML**:

```
<select>
 <option value='p'>p</option> 
 <option value='q' selected>q</option>
 <option value='r'>r</option> 
 <option value='s'>s</option> 
</select>


<input type='button' value='click me!'/> <br/> 
 ResultA : <span id='ResultA'>
    here
</span> <br/> 
 ResultB : <span id='ResultB'>
    here
</span> <br/>
```

**Javascript**:

```
function SetResult(ResultObj, ElementObj) {
    ResultObj.text("length=" + ElementObj.length + " " + "val()=" + ElementObj.val());
}

$(function() {
    $('input[type=button]').click(function() {
        var SelectObj = $('select');
        SetResult($("#ResultA"), SelectObj.find('option[selected]'));
        SetResult($("#ResultB"), SelectObj.find('option').filter('[selected]'));
    });
});
```

### Test Result:

```
+---------------------------+--------------+---------------------+---------+-----+
|          Browser          | Environment  |       jQuery        |    A    |  B  |
+---------------------------+--------------+---------------------+---------+-----+
| Chrome 22.0.1229.94m      | Win7         | 1.8.2, 1.7.2, 1.6.4 | default | new |
| Chrome 23.0.1271.64 m     | Win7         | 1.8.2, 1.7.2, 1.6.4 | default | new |
| Firefox 15.0.1            | Win7         | 1.8.2, 1.7.2, 1.6.4 | default | new |
| Firefox 16.0.2            | Win7         | 1.8.2, 1.7.2, 1.6.4 | default | new |
| IE 6                      | WinXP        | 1.8.2, 1.7.2, 1.6.4 | *new*   | new |
| IE 9                      | Win7         | 1.8.2, 1.7.2, 1.6.4 | default | new |
| Opera 12.02               | Win7         | 1.8.2, 1.7.2, 1.6.4 | default | new |
| Opera 12.10               | Win7         | 1.8.2, 1.7.2, 1.6.4 | default | new |
| Safari 5.1.7 (7534.57.2)  | Win7         | 1.8.2, 1.7.2, 1.6.4 | default | new |
+---------------------------+--------------+---------------------+---------+-----+
| Chrome 22.0.1229.94       | MacOS 10.7.5 | 1.8.2, 1.7.2, 1.6.4 | default | new |
| Chrome 23.0.1271.64       | MacOS 10.7.5 | 1.8.2, 1.7.2, 1.6.4 | default | new |
| Firefox 13.0              | MacOS 10.7.5 | 1.8.2, 1.7.2, 1.6.4 | default | new |
| Firefox 14.0.1            | MacOS 10.7.5 | 1.8.2, 1.7.2, 1.6.4 | default | new |
| Firefox 16.0.2            | MacOS 10.7.5 | 1.8.2, 1.7.2, 1.6.4 | default | new |
| Opera 12.01               | MacOS 10.7.5 | 1.8.2, 1.7.2, 1.6.4 | default | new |
| Opera 12.10               | MacOS 10.7.5 | 1.8.2, 1.7.2, 1.6.4 | default | new |
| Safari 6.0.1 (7536.26.14) | MacOS 10.7.5 | 1.8.2, 1.7.2, 1.6.4 | default | new |
+---------------------------+--------------+---------------------+---------+-----+
| Chrome 21.0.1180.82       | iOS 4.3.5    | 1.8.2, 1.7.2, 1.6.4 | default | new |
| Opera 7.0.5               | iOS 4.3.5    | 1.8.2               | default | new |
| Safari                    | iOS 4.3.5    | 1.8.2, 1.7.2, 1.6.4 | default | new |
+---------------------------+--------------+---------------------+---------+-----+
```

- *default* means it returns the *default* selected `option`.
- *new* means it returns the *new* selected `option`.

As you can see, all browsers except IE6 give different results.

Comment: Your understanding of CSS selectors seems sound. However, jQuery does not always base selectors on the source markup. This is especially true, I've found, for attribute selectors with values that can change. No idea why jQuery would treat these inconsistently, though.

Comment: Side note: using `option:selected` instead of `option[selected]` for the `#ResultA` will produce the same output as `#ResultB`.

Comment: @sp00m: I'm starting to really really hate Sizzle a lot.

Comment: There was an issue with these selectors not returning the same value in jQuery versions older than 1.7 - see this [bug report](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/10017)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### What should the expressions return?

`[selected]` matches all elements that has a `selected` attribute, with any value (references: [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#attribute-selectors), [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/)).

---

### Why are the results inconsistent?

I have submitted a bug report to jQuery [here](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/12830). It is marked as a duplicate of [another bug report](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/11115) which is **now fixed**.

---

### Any solutions?

To get the **current selection**:

Use the [`:selected`](http://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/) selector (live demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ugXtx/11/)):

```
$('select').find('option').filter(':selected'); /* Supposedly faster */
or
$('select').find('option:selected');            /* Supposedly slower */
```

Note that the 2nd expression is supposedly *slower*, according to the [doc](http://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/).

> Because `:selected` is a jQuery extension and not part of the CSS specification, queries using `:selected` cannot take advantage of the performance boost provided by the native DOM `querySelectorAll()` method.

To get the **default selection**:

For **jQuery 1.9+**, use any of the expressions as in the question, i.e.

```
/* A */ $('select').find('option[selected]');
/* B */ $('select').find('option').filter('[selected]');
```

For **jQuery 1.6+**, make use of the `defaultSelected` property (live demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ugXtx/12/), references: [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_option_defaultselected.asp), [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/HTMLOptionElement), [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533716(VS.85).aspx), [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms533716(v=vs.85).aspx)):

```
$('select').find('option').filter(function() {
    return $(this).prop('defaultSelected');
});
```

Answer (score 3):

The Sizzle engine checks the `selected` *property* of an element (which contains the *current* value) rather than the *attribute* which contains the original (default) value.

See https://github.com/jquery/sizzle/blob/master/sizzle.js#L788

What I haven't figured out yet is why your second selector apparently invokes Sizzle, but the first one doesn't seem to.

In any event, the property is what you should be checking rather than the attribute, so you should be using the `:selected` pseudo-selector, and not `[selected]`

Comment: dmethvin explains the difference in [this issue](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/10017): the problem of `:selected` going through the JavaScript path of Sizzle and looking a properties, whereas `[selected]` goes through the querySelectorAll path and looks at attributes. (Unless there is some other non-qSA selector in the string, such as `[selected]:first`.)

Comment: @Mottie indeed, except that I used the debugger and found that `.filter('[selected]')` didn't go through the `:selected` Sizzle code.  Odd...

Answer (score 1):

when you write `option[selected]` it will search for the `selected` attribute/property
instead of that you should use `option:selected` 
if you have `readonly` property and you code `option[readonly]` it will return `s`

$('[attribute]') will selects elements that have the specified attribute, with any value.
for more information : [Has Attribute Selector [name]](http://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/)

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pintu31/ugXtx/5/)**

```
<select>
 <option value='p'>p</option> 
 <option value='q' selected>q</option>
 <option value='r'>r</option> 
 <option value='s' readonly>s</option> 
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

This depends on how the DOM is constructed by the browser.. using `option[selected]` jQuery search for an option element having the selected attribute which in some cases it doesn't applied

You should use

```
SelectObj.children(':selected')
```

Comment: `.filter('[selected]')` filters options having the selected attribute too... The question is why.

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation is wrong it's not

```
find('option[selected]')
```

It should be,

```
SelectObj.find('option:selected')
```

Here's the edited fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/ugXtx/6/

and reference:

http://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/